# Slice of structs to unsorted list with mustache

Tags: templates, go, mustache

I have a struct.

```
type DataKey struct {
    Id        int64     `db:"id"`
    UserId    string    `db:"user_id"`
    Data      string    `db:"data"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `db:"created_at"`
}
```

I create a slice of structs.

```
data := []DataKey{}
```

After doing a sql query and filling the slices I try to pass to [mustache](https://godoc.org/github.com/hoisie/mustache#RenderFileInLayout) to build my list.

```
mustache.RenderFileInLayout("templates/datakeys.html.mustache", "templates/layout.html.mustache", user, data)))
```

datakeys.html.mustache

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>UserID</th>
        <th>DataKey</th>
        <th>CreatedAt</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
{{#DataKey}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{Id}}</td>
        <td>{{UserId}}</td>
        <td>{{Data}}</td>
        <td>{{CreatedAt}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/DataKey}}
</table>
```

The only thing I get is the table header. This function does not return an error so I don't know why it didn't like the data. I have also tried passing it in as a reference.

Comment: If you're using a random 3rd party library you should provide a link to it. [godoc](https://godoc.org/?q=mustache]) shows multiple packages called mustache so just mentioning by name is unhelpful.

Comment: Good point. This is the one I am using to clarify.
godoc.org/github.com/hoisie/mustache

Comment: Gah! That package is completely non-idomatic and **horrible** with errors. It has a single `string` return value and it rams `err.Error()` into it if it encounters an error. That is **bad**. **Never**, ever do that! And refuse to use any package that does. (It should of course return `(string, error)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not familiar with mustache but from looking at it I think the {{#DataKey}} is wrong.

From the docs:

Template:

```
{{#repo}}
  <b>{{name}}</b>
{{/repo}}
```

Hash:

```
{
  "repo": [
    { "name": "resque" },
    { "name": "hub" },
    { "name": "rip" }
  ]
}
```

Output:

```
<b>resque</b>
<b>hub</b>
<b>rip</b>
```

I'd suggest trying the following

```
viewModel := struct{
    items []DataKey{}
}{
    data
}

mustache.RenderFileInLayout("templates/datakeys.html.mustache", "templates/layout.html.mustache", user, viewModel )))
```

and then replace the template with

```
{{#items}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{Id}}</td>
        <td>{{UserId}}</td>
        <td>{{Data}}</td>
        <td>{{CreatedAt}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/items}}
```

This is untested and might not be correct, but might be worth trying. My guess is that DataKey isn't a property on the model hence it's failing to evaluate.

Edit for more clarity: In theory

```
viewModel := struct{
    items []DataKey{}
}{
    data
}
```

will become

```
{
    "items": [
        {...},{...} ... etc
    ]
}
```